# Why does nulls_last=False not put the nulls first in Django?

Tags: django

I'm finding that while `nulls_last=True` works, `nulls_last=False` doesn't.  Example below is in a Django shell.

```
In [10]: [x.date for x in Model.objects.all().order_by(F('date').asc(nulls_last=True))]                                                                                                                               
Out[10]: 

[datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 10, 16, 58, 7, 768401, tzinfo=<UTC>),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 10, 17, 4, 51, 601980, tzinfo=<UTC>),
 None,
 ]

[ins] In [11]: [x.last_run_created_at for x in Model.objects.all().order_by(F('date').asc(nulls_last=False))]                                                                                                                              
Out[11]: 
[datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 10, 16, 58, 7, 768401, tzinfo=<UTC>),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 10, 17, 4, 51, 601980, tzinfo=<UTC>),
 None,
 ]

In [12]:
```

I've tried this with both `desc()` and `asc()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mistake is assuming that the opposite of `nulls_last=True` is `nulls_last=False`.  It isn't.

`nulls_last=True` does the following to the query:

```
SELECT ... ORDER BY ... ASC NULLS LAST
```

Whereas `nulls_last=False` just means use the DB default:

```
SELECT ... ORDER BY ... ASC
```

What you want instead is to use `nulls_first=True` OR `nulls_last=True` to explicitly get the order you want.

This is mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-to-sort-null-values), but perhaps not as explicitly as it could be:

> Using F() to sort null values
>
> Use F() and the nulls_first or
>   nulls_last keyword argument to Expression.asc() or desc() to control
>   the ordering of a field’s null values. By default, the ordering
>   depends on your database.